# I Got a wrong cart total when i add another product

Tags: php

Im trying to create a php cart that compute a correct input in the cart when i  try to put only one product the total amount is correct but when in input another item the total amount is different

Is there something wrong with the code??

I've got a correct cart total when i add only 1 product in the cart
but when i add another when the cart total is different 
below is the code i have so far?

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("admin/php/connect_to_mysql.php");
    include("admin/php/myFunctions.php");

    if(!empty($_GET['prodid'])){
        $pid = $_GET['prodid'];
        $wasFound = false;
        $i = 0;
        if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1){
            $_SESSION["cart_array"]=array(0=>array("productID"=>$pid,"quantity"=>1));
        }else{
            foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_product){
                $i++;
                while(list($key,$value)=each($each_product)){
                    if($key=="productID" && $value==$pid){  
                        array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"],$i-1,1,array(array("productID"=>$pid,"quantity"=>$each_product ['quantity']+1)));
                        $wasFound=true;
                    }
                }       
            }
            if($wasFound==false){
                array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"],array("productID"=>$pid,"quantity"=>1));
            }
        }
        header("location:shoppingcart.php");
        exit();
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        $submit = false;
if(isset($_POST['btnUpdate'])){
    $submit = $_POST['btnUpdate'];
 } 
    echo $submit; 
    if($submit == "Update"){
        $x = 0;
        $i=0;
        //echo $_POST['txtQuan2'];
        //echo $_POST['txtHoldProdId0'];
        foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_product){
            $i++;
            $quantity = $_POST['txtQuan'.$x];
            $prodStock = $_POST['txtHoldQuan'.$x];
            $prodAdjustId = $_POST['txtHoldProdId'.$x++];
            if($quantity<1){ $quantity = 1; }
            if($quantity>$prodStock){ $quantity = $prodStock; }
            while(list($key,$value)=each($each_product)){
                array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"],$i-1,1,array(array("productID"=>$prodAdjustId,"quantity"=>$quantity)));
            }       
        }

    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if(!empty($_GET['cid']) || isset($_GET['cid'])){
        $removeKey = $_GET['cid'];
        if(count($_SESSION["cart_array"])<=1){
            unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
        }else{
            unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["$removeKey"]);
            sort($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
        }
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $cartTitle = "";
    $cartOutput = "";
    $cartTotal = "";
    if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1){
        $cartOutput="<h2 align='center'> Your shopping cart is empty </h2>";
    }else{
        $x = 0;
        $cartTitle .= '<form name="shoppingcart_form" action="shoppingcart.php" method="post" /><table width="700px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                            <th width="220" align="left">Image </th> 
                            <th width="140" align="left">Name </th> 
                            <th width="100" align="center">Quantity </th> 
                            <th width="60" align="center">Stock </th> 
                            <th width="60" align="right">Price </th> 
                            <th width="60" align="right">Total </th> 
                            <th width="90"> </th></tr>';
        $i = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_product){
            $product_id = $each_product['productID'];
            $sql=mysql_query("select * from tblproduct where prod_id='$product_id' limit 1");
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $prodNo = $row["prod_no"];
                $prodID = $row["prod_id"];
                $prodName = $row["prod_name"];
                $prodPrice = $row["prod_price"];
                $prodQuan = $row["prod_quan"];
            }
            $pricetotal=$prodPrice*$each_product['quantity'];
            $cartTotal= number_format($pricetotal+$cartTotal,2);
            $cartOutput .= '<tr><td><img style="border: 2px solid;" src="images/product/'.$prodNo.'.jpg" width="150" height="120" /></td> 
                <td>'.$prodName.'</td> 
                <td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="txtHoldProdId'.$i.'" value="'.$prodID.'" /><input name="txtQuan'.$i.'" type="text" value="'.$each_product['quantity'].'" style="width: 40px; text-align: center" /> </td>
                <td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="txtHoldQuan'.$i.'" value="'.$prodQuan.'" /> '.$prodQuan   .' pcs</td> 
                <td align="right">Php '.$prodPrice.'</td> 
                <td align="right">Php '.$pricetotal.'</td>
                <td align="center"> <a href="shoppingcart.php?cid='.$i++.'"><img src="images/remove_x.gif" alt="remove" /><br />Remove</a> </td></tr>';
        }
        $_SESSION['checkoutCartTotal'] = $cartTotal;
        $cartOutput .= '<tr>
                            <td colspan="3" align="right"  height="40px">Have you modified your basket? Please click here to <input class="btn_upd" type="submit" name="btnUpdate" value="Update" />&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align="right" style="background:#ccc; font-weight:bold"> Total: </td>
                            <td colspan="2" align="left" style="background:#ccc; font-weight:bold;">Php '.$cartTotal.' </td>
                            <td style="background:#ccc; font-weight:bold"> </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div style="float:right; width: 215px; margin-top: 20px;">

                        <div class="checkout"><a href="checkout.php" class="more">Proceed to Checkout</a></div>

                    </div></form>';
    }
?>
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    header("location:login.php");
    exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Manila Ensembles - Cart</title>
<link href="css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ddsmoothmenu.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function clearText(field)
    {
        if (field.defaultValue == field.value) field.value = '';
        else if (field.value == '') field.value = field.defaultValue;
    }
</script>

</head>

<body id="subpage">

<div id="main_wrapper">
        <?php include("header.php"); ?>
 <!-- END of header -->

    <div id="main_menu" class="ddsmoothmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="products.php">Products</a></li>
            <li><a class="selected" href="shoppingcart.php">Cart</a></li>
            <li><a href="checkout.php">Checkout</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br style="clear: left" />
    </div> <!-- end of menu -->

    <div class="cleaner h20"></div>
    <div id="main_top"></div>
    <div id="main">

                     <?php include("sidebar.php");?>
 <!-- END of sidebar -->

        <div id="content">
        <?php echo $cartTitle; ?>
        <?php echo $cartOutput; ?>

        </div> <!-- end of content -->
        <div class="cleaner"></div>
    </div> <!-- END of main -->

        <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
<!-- END of footer -->   

</div>


<script type='text/javascript' src='js/logging.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using prepared statements. Learn to use prepared statements. Please. For the sanity of all the people you'll work with in the future. Also, mysql_query is deprecated and is removed in php7. Use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: thanks for the advise

Comment: Also to solve your problem I suggest you make a `Cart` class and add `Items` to the `Cart`. You can then iterate the cart items and add them all up to get a `total()`